# i am using <g:remoteField> in grails to search payments by its code

Tags: grails

```
<label><b>Code</b></label>
<g:remoteField name="code" action="paymentsSearch" update="content" paramName="code" />
</span>
```

this is the code i m using.

after entering every letter it is calling paymentsSearch action.

but i would like to make call to paymentsSearch action after i enter whole value in the field and then press enter or click on outside of field.

Answer (score 0):

The tag in question is specifically for sending

> its value to a remote link when it changes

see: http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/remoteField.html

I would have a go with a formRemote tag (http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/formRemote.html) and either use some JQuery to trigger the submit when you click out of the field or a submit button to respond to the enter key press.